# Not showing image and content in first page of PDF in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, xslt

Not showing image and content in first page of chrome PDF viewer but when we save PDF it shows correctly all pages.I have use XSLT to generate format for PDF .My code for this is as below

```
using (MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
            iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 40f, 10f, 40f, 36);

            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

            StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();

            htmlparser.Style = style;
            PdfWriter myPDFWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, myMemoryStream);

            pdfDoc.Open();

            htmlparser.Parse(sr);

            HTMLWorker htmlparser1 = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            StyleSheet style1 = new StyleSheet();
            htmlparser1.Style = style1;

            pdfDoc.Close();

            content = AddPageNumbers(myMemoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Please share a sample PDF. The Chrome viewer has some deficiencies, so chances are that it is to blame, but to be sure, one would have to analyze sample outputs.

Comment: I can not share PDF screen shot now its confidential. When we save a PDF file it shows correctly but not in chrome browser.When we increase our image height it shows correctly in chrome but not in every case.So we want a generic solution to this problem.

Comment: **a)** you use `HtmlWorker`, a class considered deprecated for many years due to deficiencies. The iText people usually tell you to first switch to `XmlWorker` and try again. **b)** the Chrome PDF viewer is known to be incomplete. Anyone using it is bound to run into issues more often than users of more complete viewers. **c)** you cannot present sample files. Thus, you cannot expect a concise analysis, let alone a *generic solution*. **d)** you don't show how you serve the file. Often problems arise there and not in the actual PDF creation.